# Why doesn't the dot symbol work in this Regex?

Tags: .net, regex

NET Regex. (with ignore-case)

I want it to match

```
field_x_12
field_a_ABC
field_r_something
```

etc

My question is why the `.` operator doesn't work in this regex:

```
field_[.]_.*
```

yet this (equivalent basically) regex does work:

```
field_[a-z]_.*
```

Is there something I'm missing about the dot operator `.` ?

Comment: Also, "." and "[a-z]" are not roughly equivalent.  The dot wildcard represents *any character*, not just alpha characters (the dot will match alpha characters, digits, special characters, unprintable characters, etc.)  What you really want is "field_\w_(?:\w|\d)*"

Comment: @Toby yes I know, but there will never be anything but alpha characters inbetween `_ _` in this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `.` inside a character class (`[...]`) is a literal dot character. If you want it to act as a wildcard, don't use the brackets.

Comment: so what you really want is field_._.* (assuming you want a single match-all char instead of only a-z)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `[.]`? The `[]` denotes a explicit set of characters, so the `.` character is what the RegEx is looking for.

```
field_._.*
```

Should work fine.

See [this](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx) handy .NET RegEx cheat sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Inside brackets `.` is a literal dot and doesn't match any character.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `field_._.*` because inside the [] it is treatd as an acutal dot.

Answer (score 0):

When it's inside a character class, the dot is just a period, not a wildcard.